# Send string into function and use string as "table"

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, table-functions

Is there a way to send in a string into a T-SQL function and use that string as a "table"

For instance

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TEST] ( @id int, **@table_name** nvarchar(50))
RETURNS @mytables TABLE
   (
    id     int,
    values nvarchar(50)
   )
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT @mytables
      SELECT id, values FROM **@table_name**
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: No, you cannot do this directly - if you need to parametrize the table and/or column names, you must resort to using *dynamic SQL* - no other way to do it

Comment: I mean, I could use another function inside this function or whatever it doesn't matter. I just want to know if it can be done and how :)

Comment: Plus: a **function** in SQL Server **cannot** have any side effects on the database, e.g. you **cannot** insert, update or delete rows of data inside a function. See [CREATE FUNCTION - section "Limitations and Restrictions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx): *User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dynamic SQL in function, also can't insert, update or delete from any table in user defined function (**Please check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) given by Marc**), for your requirements, SP is best solution like this way :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] (@id int, @table_name nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    declare @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    set @strSQL = ' SELECT ' + cast(@id as varchar(20)) + ', Name from ' + @table_name
    exec(@strSQL)
END
```

and run that SP by

```
EXEC [TEST] @id=5, @table_name='tablename'
```

Comment: I guess this is the only way. The only problem is that the str can only be 4000 char and I need it to be much bigger.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: where you faced problem of 4000 chars ? In string you just pass table name, right ?

Comment: This was just an example. The one I want to create is much larger than that :)
BTW can i skip the declare @strSQL and just to a SELECT directly in the store procedure??

Comment: Then you can use VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) for large strings

Comment: Yes but my max is 4000 characters. Could I create a store procedure and mix your solution with just plain select 
like 
declare (at)strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    set (at)strSQL = ' SELECT ' + cast((at)id as varchar(20)) + ', Name from ' + (at)table_name
    exec((at)strSQL)
UNION ALL select id, name from table2

Comment: @Joe: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` can hold up to **1 billion** characters - not just 4000 ...

Comment: @marc_s: Can NVARCHAR(MAX) be used with sql 2000 as welL? and contain a billion characters?

Comment: @Joe: **no** - `NVARCHAR(max)` is a new feature in SQL Server **2005** (you didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using - you should, with every question, just makes it easier for us to respond with appropriate advice). SQL Server 2000 is ancient history, I typically assume people are on 2005 or newer

Comment: @marc_s: Ok yeah sorry about that! Thanks for the help though! To both of you!